# Problems defining JSON API data in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Am trying to use Jquery to get data from an API and update the API URL based on a select box option. However, there is something wrong with my code in the below snippet. It is meant to allow the user the option to select a date range (default of 30 days as value) and `onchange` the API URL is updated, using AJAX also allows the HTML content to be updated.

```js
function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, data => {

    let visitors;
    let uniq_visitors;
    let pageviews;
    let uniq_pageviews;
    let actions;
    let outlinks;
    let bounces;
    let avgtime;
    for (i in data) {
      let a = data[i].nb_visitors;
      if (a) {
        visitors += a;
      }
      let b = data[i].nb_uniq_visitors;
      if (b) {
        uniq_visitors += b;
      }
      let c = data[i].nb_pageviews;
      if (c) {
        pageviews += c;
      }
      let d = data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
      if (d) {
        uniq_pageviews += a;
      }
      let e = data[i].nb_actions;
      if (e) {
        actions += b;
      }
      let f = data[i].nb_outlinks;
      if (f) {
        outlinks += c;
      }
      let g = data[i].bounce_count;
      if (g) {
        bounces += c;
      }
      let h = data[i].avg_time_on_site;
      if (h) {
        avgtime += c;
      }
    }
    $("#visitors").html(visitors);
    $("#uniq_visitors").html(uniq_visitors);
    $("#pageviews").html(pageviews);
    $("#uniq_pageviews").html(uniq_pageviews);
    $("#actions").html(actions);
    $("#outlinks").html(outlinks);
    $("#bounces").html(bounces);
    $("#avgtime").html(avgtime);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="return datePeriod();">
            <option selected value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
            <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
            <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
          </select>

<span id="DateShow"></span>

<p id="visitors"></p>
<p id="uniq_visitors"></p>
<p id="pageviews"></p>
<p id="uniq_pageviews"></p>
<p id="actions"></p>
<p id="outlinks"></p>
<p id="bounces"></p>
<p id="avgtime"></p>
```

As seen in the snippet, whilst the select box works with #DateShow the return values of the JSON are not displaying. JSON is retrieved as example `{"2017-12-18":{"nb_uniq_visitors":1,"nb_visits":1,"nb_users‌​":0...}}`, seen here https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff

I want the `keys` as per date to be totalled over the set period from the select box, i.e. if a user selects `last 90 days` the API URL is changed to `https://...date=last90...`. The content of each should be updated with the new JSON data.

Comment: In your `onchange` you have it returning the function. Try removing the `return`.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this but it is still not displaying the JSON data. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it may be that I have not defined the data wanted correctly with the JSON output. A little lost in doing so, the data is shown as `{"2017-12-18":{"nb_uniq_visitors":1,"nb_visits":1,"nb_users":0...}}` by date and the values shown should be all values by date added together.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific with what is currently happening in what you have? Do you have any logs anywhere?

Comment: I have added more to my question. If you need more information please do not hesitate in asking. Thanks again.

Comment: If you log out `data[i]` what does it display in the console?

Comment: Nothing is being logged in the console, even when requesting as the only function.

Comment: This may be because your javascript function comes after the `onChange` in the source, see my answer

Comment: Sorry, I do get the array in the console, only after selecting from the select box but the console is not returned. The console looks like `2017-12-18
{nb_uniq_visitors: 1, nb_visits: 1, nb_users: 0, nb_actions: 5, max_actions: 5, …}` across all dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems I can see...

- You have a return in the onChange, as QuietOran said. remove it.
- If you are loading / inserting your javascript at the end of the document, it wont work because the `datePeriod` function will be undefined when the onChange is read in the source. I can't tell if this is a problem as I can't see from your post how/when you are loading the javascript. To fix it, either have your function defined before the onChange, or attach the event listener with `addEventListener()` or the jquery eqivilent which I think is:
  `$('#DateSelector').on('change', function(){//do stuff})`
- You are trying to use `data[i].nb_visitors`, which should probably be `data[i].nb_visits`.
- Check your additions within your if statements, a few are wrong, for example, when you are checking d, you are adding a.

  `if (d) {
    uniq_pageviews += a; // this is wrong I think
  }`

With these few problems fixed, it seems to work, though the summed data for 30, 90 and 365 days seems to add up to the same values.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, (data) => {

//console.log(data);
    let visitors = 0;
    let uniq_visitors = 0;
    let pageviews = 0;
    let uniq_pageviews = 0;
    let actions = 0;
    let outlinks = 0;
    let bounces = 0;
    let avgtime = 0;
    
    for (i in data) {
     
      if (data[i].nb_visits) {
        visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_visitors) {
        uniq_visitors += data[i].nb_uniq_visitors;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_pageviews) {
        pageviews += data[i].nb_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews) {
        uniq_pageviews += data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_actions) {
        actions += data[i].nb_actions;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_outlinks) {
        outlinks += data[i].nb_outlinks;
      }
      if (data[i].bounce_count) {
        bounces += data[i].bounce_count;
      }
      if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
        avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
      }
    }

    $("#visitors").html(visitors);
    $("#uniq_visitors").html(uniq_visitors);
    $("#pageviews").html(pageviews);
    $("#uniq_pageviews").html(uniq_pageviews);
    $("#actions").html(actions);
    $("#outlinks").html(outlinks);
    $("#bounces").html(bounces);
    $("#avgtime").html(avgtime);
  });
}
</script>

<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="datePeriod();">
            <option selected value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
            <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
            <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
          </select>

<span id="DateShow"></span>

<p id="visitors"></p>
<p id="uniq_visitors"></p>
<p id="pageviews"></p>
<p id="uniq_pageviews"></p>
<p id="actions"></p>
<p id="outlinks"></p>
<p id="bounces"></p>
<p id="avgtime"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the `<script>` in the footer. The only thing I do have is no default of 30 days. Thanks again.